# How do I programmatically add an event listener which is index depended in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am trying to add an even listener programmatically, to a photoshop plugin using this code:

```
actionObject = [];
actionObject[0] =  {name: "A1", id: "95ce"};
actionObject[1] =  {name: "B2", id: "9dk2"};
.
.
actionObject[10] =  {name: "H6", id: "9334"};


for (i = 0; i < actionObject.length; i++ ){
    console.log("#btn" + actionObject[i].name);
    var action = actionObject[i];
    $("#btn" + action.name).click(async function () {
        await ExecuteAsModal(() => runAction(action));
    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when this even is triggered, regardless of the button I am pressing, it always tries to run "runAction" with the last 'action' in the actionObject array.
In this case it always tries to run it with

```
action={name: "H6", id: "9334"}
```

How can Make sure each button runs "actionObject" with it's proper "action"?

Comment: Its an issue with closure. You'll want to use an arrow function. `.click(async () => { ...})`

Comment: I change it like this and it still tries to run the action with the last index in the array: ` var action = actionObject[i];
    $("#btn" + action.name).click(async () => { 
        await ExecuteAsModal(() => runAction(action));
    });`

Comment: @cs95: An arrow function does solve this. The "closure rules" for both are the same.

Comment: The shortest solution would be to change `var action = ...` to `let action = ...`. `let` declarations are block-scoped.

Comment: Yes, "let" did it.